# Making sure given string contains either iframe or object tags

Tags: php

We are adding embeddable content that users can add. This opens up for a lot of exploits, and i want to start minimizing the potential damage.

First off I need to make sure the embeddable string starts with either `<iframe>` or `<object>` and ends with `</iframe>` or `</object>`

Found this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28118798/how-can-i-check-a-string-is-iframe-tag-by-php-functions

but I need to rewrite it, and I'm at a loss.

```
$string = '<iframe src="sourceurl"></iframe>';
$test = strpos($string,'<iframe');
if (!empty($test)) {
    echo 'That has an iframe!!';
} else {
    echo 'There's no iframe in there...';
}
```

How do I attack this? And on a sidenote, should I just scrap object embeds? They feel highly vulnerable..

Comment: have a look at http://php.net/manual/de/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: Is your ``$string`` variable containing **only** ``<iframe src="src"></iframe>`` ?

Comment: string can be embeddable codes from one of thousand different embeddable content providers.. youtube, vimeo etc.

Comment: Thanks @donald123 ! that looks like the way to go!

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because `<iframe` is at the beginning of your `$string` meaning that `strpos` will return 0 cause the `<ifrma` start from the position 0
and because  `empty(0)` will return `true` (meaning it is empty) which is not true in our cause because 0 in our case means something.

to solve this problem just replace `!empty($test)` with `$test >= 0` something like this :

```
$string = '<iframe src="sourceurl"></iframe>';
$test = strpos($string,'<iframe');

//in this case $test = 0 cause it is at the start of the string

if ($test >= 0) {
  echo 'That has an iframe!!';
} else {
  echo 'There\'s no iframe in there...';
}

// you can even use Regular Expressions 
// to ensure that your string starts with <iframe , here is an example : 

// ^ : means start with.
if(preg_match('/^<iframe /',$string)){
    echo 'That has an iframe using Regular Expressions!!';      
}
```

Hope it helps.